# Is it necessary to set the /stopcasting macro in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Does the top pvp player set the /stopcasting macro and make a key-binding with that in the world of warcraft? Is it necessary? Or just move the character to break the casting spell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**: It depends.

**Long answer**:

- If you're simply trying to stop casting of a spell with no following action, then moving is just fine and is preferred so you don't waste a keybinding on doing essentially the same thing.
- If you want to stop casting as part of a macro that is going to do something else like "fire off an emergency heal", then using the /stopcasting command is better.

Comment: Note that if you're a Fire mage with the talent Firestarter, and you have Molten Armor active, you can cast Scorch while moving - so in that case, you *do* need /stopcasting if you want to be able to stop it. I don't know if any other classes have similar talents, but the same thing would apply for those.

Comment: Hunters have Aspect of the Fox.

Comment: Shaman have Spiritwalker's Grace

Answer (score 5):

Please note that stopcasting will step on itself, meaning if you spam the macro below, you won't cast anything as you will be interrupting the Heal to cast another Heal.

```
/stopcasting
/cast Heal
```